# FirebaseUI Inflating exception

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui, godot

Hello I am trying to use Firebase-UI 4.3.1 in my android mobile application that I am creating using Godot engine. I am already using successfully Firebase-Firestore API in my app. I am compiling whole Godot engine with my small Java modules and running application. However Firebase-UI 4.3.1 (i tried 4.3.0 also) does not work correctly when app is running. I want to support login methods for facebook,gmail and email. First two options are working correctly but when I click on "Login with email" button app craches with following errors:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.godotengine.bacterio/com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.email.EmailActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable org.godotengine.godot:drawable/design_password_eye with resource ID #0x7f07008f

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v21/design_password_eye.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f07008f
```

I have tried different versions of com.android.support.* libreries like 27.1.1, I have tried different complie SDK versions but nothing helped. I though the resources were not added to apk correctly when multiDex was used togather with Godot but after checking generated APK resources.arsc file and folder i can see ones mentioned in error. So I am not sure if resources are real problem here or not.
[RES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A2gK.png)

Here are build file and manifest of apk that I am building successfully:

```html
buildscript {
 repositories {
   maven {
 url 'https://maven.google.com'
 }

  jcenter()
 }
 dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1"

 }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

allprojects {
    repositories {
  maven {
 url 'https://maven.google.com'
 }

     jcenter()
 mavenCentral()
 google()
    }
}

dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
 compile ('com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'){exclude group: 'com.android.support' exclude module: 'appcompat-v7' exclude module: 'support-v4'}
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
 compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.33.0'
 compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.1'
 compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'){force = true}
 compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'){force = true}
 compile ('com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'){force = true}
 compile ('com.android.support:design:28.0.0'){force = true}
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
 
}

android {

 lintOptions {
  abortOnError false
  disable 'MissingTranslation'
 }

 compileSdkVersion 28
 buildToolsVersion "28.0.3" 
 useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

 packagingOptions {
  exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
  exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
 }
 defaultConfig {
  generatedDensities = []
  applicationId 'org.godotengine.godot'
  targetSdkVersion 27
  multiDexEnabled true
  minSdkVersion 18
  
 }
 // Both signing and zip-aligning will be done at export time
 buildTypes.all { buildType ->
  buildType.zipAlignEnabled false
  buildType.signingConfig null
 }
 sourceSets {
  main {
   manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
   java.srcDirs = ['src'
    ,'/home/user/godot/godot-3.0.6-stable/modules/projectx_auth/src','/home/user/godot/godot-3.0.6-stable/modules/projectx_db/src','/home/user/godot/godot-3.0.6-stable/modules/projectx_gps/src'
   ]
   res.srcDirs = [
    'res'
    ,'/home/user/godot/godot-3.0.6-stable/modules/projectx_auth/res'
   ]
   aidl.srcDirs = [
    'aidl'
    
   ]
   assets.srcDirs = [
    'assets'
    
   ]
  }
  debug.jniLibs.srcDirs = [
   'libs/debug'
   
  ]
  release.jniLibs.srcDirs = [
   'libs/release'
   
  ]
 }
 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  // ApplicationVariant is undocumented, but this method is widely used; may break with another version of the Android Gradle plugin
  variant.outputs.get(0).setOutputFile(new File("${projectDir}/../../../bin", "android_${variant.name}.apk"))
 }
}

apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.godot.game"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0"
      android:installLocation="auto"
      >
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <application android:label="@string/godot_project_name_string" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:allowBackup="false" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
 >
        <activity android:name="org.godotengine.godot.Godot"
                  android:label="@string/godot_project_name_string"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:launchMode="singleTask"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
                  android:resizeableActivity="false">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
 <service android:name="org.godotengine.godot.GodotDownloaderService" />






    </application>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" android:required="true" />



<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" android:targetSdkVersion="28"/>

</manifest>
```

Any help and advice what to try will be really appricieted.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue I was able to solve it. You can find how here and what was the root cause [issue resolution](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1600)